Xcode Swift Google Admob Integration Issues
I am working on integrating a Google Banner Ad into an Xcode Project similar to how it is shown in the video linked below:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OLs5dVRdN3c&t=10s
I first create my Xcode project, open the terminal and do the "pod init", "open podfile", insert the line that says "pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'", and then "pod install". When I do this, I get two errors within my Xcode Workspace:
Sandbox: bash(47910) deny(1) file-write-create /Users/UserName/Desktop/ApplicationName/Pods/resources-to-copy-ApplicationName.txt
and
:20: error: Unexpected failure
If I skip one step and do not insert the "pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'" line, I do not get this error.
This is odd because I have created apps with these ads before, and have never had this issue.
Does anybody have any ideas as to how I should fix these errors?
